# PayPal Variable Price Smart Button Does Not Execute Without User Input?

Tags: javascript, paypal, checkout, paypal-adaptive-payments, payment-processing

PayPal's Smart Button checkout for variable pricing has an extra field that's purpose for needing to be user defined wasn't very clear.

Even something as basic as pre filing in the values of the inputs fields stops it from functioning correctly. e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="descriptionInput" id="description" maxlength="127" value="My Item Description">
```

Code generator here: https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart

My aim is to have a variable price form where the user can change the value amount, but no user input is required if they are satisfied with the predefined suggestion inside the input field already, how ever unless there is some user input in either the blank description field or the payment amount field the button script does not execute.

How can I allow the Paypal button to execute without requiring any user input in either field?

**An example of the code:**

```
<div id="smart-button-container">
    <div style="text-align: center"><label for="description"> </label><input type="text" name="descriptionInput" id="description" maxlength="127" value=""></div>
      <p id="descriptionError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please enter a description</p>
    <div style="text-align: center"><label for="amount"> </label><input name="amountInput" type="number" id="amount" value="" ><span> USD</span></div>
      <p id="priceLabelError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please enter a price</p>
    <div id="invoiceidDiv" style="text-align: center; display: none;"><label for="invoiceid"> </label><input name="invoiceid" maxlength="127" type="text" id="invoiceid" value="" ></div>
      <p id="invoiceidError" style="visibility: hidden; color:red; text-align: center;">Please enter an Invoice ID</p>
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0.625rem;" id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=USD" data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
  <script>
  function initPayPalButton() {
    var description = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #description');
    var amount = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #amount');
    var descriptionError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #descriptionError');
    var priceError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #priceLabelError');
    var invoiceid = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceid');
    var invoiceidError = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceidError');
    var invoiceidDiv = document.querySelector('#smart-button-container #invoiceidDiv');

    var elArr = [description, amount];

    if (invoiceidDiv.firstChild.innerHTML.length > 1) {
      invoiceidDiv.style.display = "block";
    }

    var purchase_units = [];
    purchase_units[0] = {};
    purchase_units[0].amount = {};

    function validate(event) {
      return event.value.length > 0;
    }

    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        color: 'gold',
        shape: 'rect',
        label: 'paypal',
        layout: 'vertical',
        
      },

      onInit: function (data, actions) {
        actions.disable();

        if(invoiceidDiv.style.display === "block") {
          elArr.push(invoiceid);
        }

        elArr.forEach(function (item) {
          item.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
            var result = elArr.every(validate);
            if (result) {
              actions.enable();
            } else {
              actions.disable();
            }
          });
        });
      },

      onClick: function () {
        if (description.value.length < 1) {
          descriptionError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          descriptionError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        if (amount.value.length < 1) {
          priceError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          priceError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        if (invoiceid.value.length < 1 && invoiceidDiv.style.display === "block") {
          invoiceidError.style.visibility = "visible";
        } else {
          invoiceidError.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        purchase_units[0].description = description.value;
        purchase_units[0].amount.value = amount.value;

        if(invoiceid.value !== '') {
          purchase_units[0].invoice_id = invoiceid.value;
        }
      },

      createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: purchase_units,
        });
      },

      onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
          alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!');
        });
      },

      onError: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }
  initPayPalButton();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're speaking of the button type: "Variable price", specifically.

Since with such a button the payer can pay any amount whatsoever, the Description field is for them to state what they are paying for, otherwise you will not know what the payment is for. The optional invoice ID that you can enable (by entering a label) is for them to enter an invoice ID, if you use such IDs.

---

If you need variable amount payments with some predefined description, set it (with autocomplete off) and hide the div.

```
<div style="text-align: center; display:none;"><label for="description">no</label><input type="text" name="descriptionInput" id="description" maxlength="127" value="my super description no one can change" autocomplete="off" /></div>
```

Comment: Yes but why does the customer have to fill that out? Why would I not be able to predefine what they are paying for and then they can choose what to pay?

Comment: And again the ID is being require to be filled out by the customer not me

Comment: If you want to predefine things, use a different button type (not Variable price).

Comment: Then I can't allow the customer to choose what they want to pay

Comment: I know preston that was said in the question, the point was what is the role of the customer choosing what the invoice ID is that seems backwards

Comment: If you don't need the invoice ID field, don't use it. If you need a variable amount button without a description, hide the description field.

Comment: Then it doesn;t work, it requires the customer to put somethere there before it works as said in the question, hense my confusion

Comment: "yet this is left blank and required for the buyer to input any random text in the field before the payment will post to the paypal login" - from question 

See I know what a description and a Invoice ID field are normally for, but for some reason PayPal seems to be using them for the customer to fill out which is the bit I'm finding confusing.

Comment: You said you wanted to predefine it, so set a value and hide it.

Comment: Again I addressed that, that doesn't work

Comment: everything I've tried so far is preventing the script from executing.

Even something as basic as pre filing in the values of the inputs fields stops it from functioning correctly. e.g.

<input type="text" name="descriptionInput" id="description" maxlength="127" value="My Item Description">

Comment: That will work fine. Turn off autocomplete if it's throwing you for a loop.

Comment: What am I failing to explain here?

Comment: Until the field has something actively typed in the input field by a user. The button DOES NOT execute

Comment: The input works fine in my test with autocomplete off

Comment: Does it work if you try to also leave in a pre-defined payment value as a default and execute without inputting anything?

Comment: You do need to input an amount in that other field

Comment: You can pre define both

Comment: If you predefine the payment value and then type something in the description field it accepts the default payment value

Comment: The JS requires at least one input to be keyed before it will validate and enable the buttons. If you predefine everything, remove the initial `actions.disable();` from onInit.

Comment: I'll update my question to be more inline with what I was after and if you alter your answer to reflect I'll mark that as the answer as even though it was a struggle you helped to get me there thank you